# why does this code just load 10 latest posts?

Tags: wordpress

Someone made this code for me to load the posts in json format but it just loads the 10 latest posts. How do I change it to load all the posts?

I tried by?page=2 but it doesn't work.

[json url](http://www.blog.atyscode.com/post.php)

code

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

include ('wp-load.php');

$loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post'));
if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    $posts[] = array(
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'post_title' => $post->post_title,
        'post_content' => $post->post_content,
        'guid' => $post->guid,

        'image' => (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : ''),
        'cats' => the_category_ID( false ),
        'post_date' => $post->post_date,
    );

endwhile; endif;
echo json_encode($posts);

?>
```

Comment: Page GET parameter is not passed into the WordPress query: `$loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post'));`

Comment: so what sould i do? i want that shows all posts in one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have taken a look at [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). There's a pre-set `posts_per_page` param which is to be set to `-1` if you want all the posts:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 )
);
```